# Why is adding display flex here into the parent not allowing me to set flex

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am writing components in react and for now trying to style using index.css(I know that is not the right way).So here is the structure[image]

Also I want to display certain number of productContainer components(let us say 3) out of a total 24. Right now everything gets displayed in the same line. I tried flex-wrap but it does not work correctly.Width also pushes everything in the same line.

I know we can fix it by using inline block or grid but I wanted a flexbox way of doing the same.

CSS:

```css
.productlist {
 display: flex;
}
.productContainer {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 340px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: flex-start;
 justify-items: flex-start;
 border-style: ridge;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 1px;
}
.item {
 width: 100px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show your css also?

Comment: can you show your `index.css` ?

Comment: added css for the same

Comment: `width: 1` is not valid CSS. `width` demands a proper length value, and anything but `0` needs a _unit_ to be one. `flex-wrap` would probably have worked, if you had specified a proper width for your items.

Comment: that was some copy paste error...I put 100px there...

Comment: Keeping in line with flexbox style: `.productContainer { flex-basis: 33%; }` instead of width.

Comment: nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You need both `wrap` and `basis` to achieve the result you want. `flex-basis` is the equivalent of `width` in flex, and `flex-wrap` will make the elements not overflow. Not specifying `flex-grow` will maintain the same size for the last elements that do not fit neatly into row (if you had odd elements, like in this example).

```css
.productlist {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* wrap items in container */
}

.productContainer {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: 33%;  /* 3 containers per row */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px ridge black;
}
```

```html
<div class="productlist">
    <div class="productContainer">
        <div class="item title">Title-1</div>
        <div class="item price">Price</div>
        <div class="item company">Company 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productContainer">
        <div class="item title">Title-2</div>
        <div class="item price">Price</div>
        <div class="item company">Company 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productContainer">
        <div class="item title">Title-3</div>
        <div class="item price">Price</div>
        <div class="item company">Company 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productContainer">
        <div class="item title">Title-4</div>
        <div class="item price">Price</div>
        <div class="item company">Company 4</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```